# Getting model's camelCase attributes, when underscored property is true

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

My model has `underscored` property set to true.

Sequelize loads such attributes well, but leaves camelCased attributes undefined. Is it a bug or intended behaviour? How to make it work?

Example:

```
User = Seq.define('User', { passwordHash: DT.STRING }, { underscored: true })

User.get(1).success(function(user) {
   user.passwordHash; // undefined
   user.password_hash; // 'some value'
})

/* table column name is 'password_hash' */
```

Comment: Seems that property relates only for timestamp attributes :(

Comment: The intended behaviour of underscored is to convert _all_ camelcase attributes to underscored style. If you want to be able to access the attribute via passwordHash, you could define a custom getter for it http://sequelizejs.com/documentation#models-getters---setters-defining-as-part-of-the-model-options